# Spring Data Query with Array of strings using @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using a Spring repository to query from MongoDB. I have a function in my repo like the one below which searches for a key-value pair in the DB.

```
@Query("{ '?0' : { $eq: ?1 } }")
public Page<GsJsonStore> matchJson(String term, String value, Pageable pageable);
```

I have to modify the query to accept an array of strings like below :

```
public Page<GsJsonStore> matchJson(String[] term, String[] value, Pageable pageable);
```

How do I modify the query to search for multiple K-V pairs using an AND/OR condition?

Like :

```
{'term[1]' : {$eq : value[1]} AND 'term[2]' : {$eq : value[2]} AND.....}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That won't work like that. FIrst of all, all MongoDB expression arguments are already "AND" conditions anyway. But mostly you are looking at building the list of conditions dynamically, for which such annotation is not supported. You are better off constructing the query object without the annotation.

Comment: I'm new to JPA, could you tell me how to construct the query object for this case? Thank you!

Comment: What I am saying is the annotation for what you want is not possible, nor does it make any real sense. A better signature here would be simply to accept a "map", just like a normal MongoDB query i.e `{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" }` ( serialized input of map/BasicDBObject ). That means *"this condition **and** that condition"* in MongoDB query speak. So noting both "and" and "eq" are already implied. Use a map, rather than a list of keys and a list of values. And use it natively. No need for a signature annotation.